# Is posible resolve devdependencies vulnerabilities on checkmarx for a angular project?

Tags: angular, security, package, dependencies, checkmarx

Checkmarx show vulnerabilities on devlibraries in angular project

I have a project with angular 15, this project is analysed with checkmarx in a jenkins pipeline, on result report show a vulnerabilities on dependencies of dev dependencies (npm-debug, inflight). I tried to update parent dependencies, but this not resolve the problem. How can I resolve this vulnerbilities for checkmarx scanning? I share with you a screenshot

[Checkmarx report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABMlG.png)

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a fix for this?

Comment: Hi!, not yet dude :(. I pursu try to solve this problem